# Why isn't salt-api working with this configuration?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, salt-stack

I'm trying to set up a really basic salt-api configuration just to test it out.  I'm using salt-master and **salt-minion 2016.3.0 Boron** on **Ubuntu 14.04**

I'm using [this tutorial](http://bencane.com/2014/07/17/integrating-saltstack-with-other-services-via-salt-api/), and my configuration is below.

**/srv/salt/top.sls**

```
base:
  '*':
      - reactor
```

**/etc/salt/master.d/reactor.conf**

```
reactor:
  - 'salt/netapi/hook/restart':
    - /srv/reactor/test.sls
```

**/srv/reactor/test.sls**

```
{% set postdata = data.get('post', {}) %}

{% if postdata.secretkey == "replacethiswithsomethingbetter"  %}
test:
  local.cmd.run:
    - tgt: '{{ postdata.tgt }}'
    -arg:
      - touch /home/username/test.txt
{% endif %}
```

I have restarted the master, and if I run `salt '*' state.sls reactor` then everything in the state works fine.  All it does is `touch /home/username/test.txt`, and that file is created when I run the state.

The command I'm running to use the API is

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -d tgt='*' -d secretkey="replacethiswithsomethingbetter" -k https://192.168.1.1:8080/hook/services/restart
```

and that command returns `{"success": true}`

Then I check on the minion, and the file hasn't been created.

The output of `salt-run state.event pretty=True` is

```
salt/netapi/hook/services/restart   {
    "_stamp": "2016-06-29T19:30:04.193832", 
    "body": "", 
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json", 
        "Content-Length": "46", 
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
        "Host": "192.168.1.1:8080", 
        "Remote-Addr": "192.168.1.3", 
        "User-Agent": "curl/7.35.0"
    }, 
    "post": {
        "secretkey": "replacethiswithsomethingbetter", 
        "tgt": "*"
    }
}
```

I did go through all of the self signed cert steps.  I'm not 100% sure why I need those, but it's done, and they are listed in the rest_cherrypy configs.

Any help is appreciated.

---

**EDIT 1**

I edited the reactor stuff, because there's an example of using cmd.run, or local.cmd.run located int he salt docs [here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/reactor/)

It's still returning true, and not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL is wrong:

```
https://192.168.1.1:8080/hook/services/restart
```

should change to :

```
https://192.168.1.1:8080/hook/restart
```

because what you defined is :

```
reactor:
  - 'salt/netapi/hook/restart':
    - /srv/reactor/test.sls
```

You can view debug log by run salt-master as `salt-master -l debug` .

Comment: This ended up not being my actual problem.  For some reason my master isn't taking '*' as a target.  So, that's a completely different problem, but I also had this as a mistake.  Thanks for the help.